# Running jMeter from AWS EC2 times out

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, jmeter

I have some jMeter scripts that I am able to run fine locally. However, when I try to run them on an EC2 instance, every thread times out with the following exception:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

If I run a curl command on EC2 instance on the same endpoint it works just fine. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this or experience with the same problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check your security groups and NACLs. This is pretty standard when something works locally but not remotely. Your question isn't very precise around where things run, if my comment doesn't help please expand your question to be more clear.

Comment: It ended up being a whitelisting issue... after a day of troubleshooting, I figured it out right after posting the question... Thanks @Tim

Comment: Please post and answer to your question that explains what the problem was, to help others, and to prevent people coming in here to try to answer the question.

Comment: @ferics2 please add an 'answer' so that this question comes off the unanswered question filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was with white listing. The EC2 instance had not been white listed to hit the end point in question. Lesson learned when experiencing these types of issues is to run a simple `curl` command to ensure the end point can actually be hit.